# ErrorSummary for multiform model

Tags: yii

I am using a multi form model. A $model array is passed to the view and for each model object I am trying to have an errorsummary. See the code below.

`foreach ($model as $f=>$edu):
echo $form->errorSummary($edu,''); 
echo $form->textField($edu,"[$f]schoolname",array('size'=>30,'maxlength'=>128));
endforeach;`

When I submit the form an error summary for only one form is displayed. Any ideas.

Comment: I think that, since you are only posting a single form at a time, there is only one validation done? No validation means no errors. As I don't see more of the code this is just a guess.

Comment: what about your controller code?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to rethink your form structure, for example - put all into one form, then inside controller make validation of every model you use and then show error messages.